# Java API Question

Tags: java, api, gwt, widget

I am trying to implement a custom Java widget using GWT.This requires me to copy a class from the GWT API and pasting it in my own new Class.(I am not sure if this is a right approach.Suggest me if its wrong to copy the API in my new class).The reason why i am doing this is i need to make modifications to the API,because the API does not provide me getter/setter's for a object.

But the problem with this is ,the API class uses many methods which have the protected access modifier.So when i paste this code in my package ,these methods are not recognized.I cannot even think of making my class a sub class (a workaround for protected access modifier) as the methods are from different classes and i cannot make my class a sub class of more than one class.

Can any one suggest me a work around for this scenario.I am trying to implement a widget whose functionality is similar to the browser's navigation widget(the place where we enter a website's url).Its similar to combining the functionality of ListBox+SuggestBox.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475277/gwt-suggestbox-listbox-widget) is my previous question.That is what i am trying to implement.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive a new widget by extending from Composite and then implement whatever functionality you need within that. e.g. If you need a ListBox to make suggestions then create one from inside your Composite and hook up whatever listeners you need to on the inner widget to drive suggestions.

A sample of a Composite widget is shown [here](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~Composite).

There shouldn't be any reason to have to copy & paste existing source code. Indeed doing so is not going to get you far since most widgets in GWT are just wrappers HTML elements anyway with some plumbing to hook up to the event model.

Comment: If one were forced to copy & paste code, it would wise to assert that the license for that code is compatible with the one under which they plan to release their software.

Comment: "There shouldn't be any reason to have to copy & paste existing source code" - exactly.  You're starting on the wrong foot there.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you provided some sample code, you should never have to copy and paste code from the API.  What are you trying to extend and what variables within that class do you need access to and to do what?  Usually there is a reason why variables are private and thats because messing with them will cause a break in functionality.