# How to auto scroll GWT SuggestBox with max-height and overflow-y: scroll?

Tags: gwt, widget, scroll

How can I auto scroll the GWT `SuggestBox` with max-height set on the `PopupPanel` holding the `SuggestBox`? Currently when the user presses keyboard up keys and down keys styles changes on the suggested items and pressing enter will select the currently selected item on the list.

When the item is located in lower than the max-height scroll bars doesn't scroll.
I tried extending the `SuggestBox` and inner class `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` to override `moveSelectionDown()` and `moveSelectionUp()` to explicitly call `popup.setScrollTop()`.

In order to do this I need access to the absolute top of the currently selected `MenuItem` therefore need access to `SuggestionMenu` which is also an inner class of SuggestBox which is private and declared as a private member within `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` without getter. Since GWT is a JavaScript we can't use reflection to access it.... Does anyone have a workaround for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, I get what you are saying. May be you need to show some code or make a fiddle to explain the problem

Comment: I've just done exactly the same

Comment: In the end, have you found any way to achieve this?
I'm stuck at the same place as you are, I need access to the currently selected MenuItem to scroll it into view.
Thanks.

Comment: I did, please take a look at the answer below, let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 4):

I've been searching around and couldn't find a proper solution (apart from reimplementing SuggestBox). The following avoids reimplementing SuggestBox:

```
private static class ScrollableDefaultSuggestionDisplay extends SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay {

    private Widget suggestionMenu;

    @Override
    protected Widget decorateSuggestionList(Widget suggestionList) {
        suggestionMenu = suggestionList;

        return suggestionList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void moveSelectionDown() {
         super.moveSelectionDown();
         scrollSelectedItemIntoView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void moveSelectionUp() {
         super.moveSelectionUp();
         scrollSelectedItemIntoView();
    }

    private void scrollSelectedItemIntoView() {
        //                                     DIV          TABLE       TBODY       TR's
        NodeList<Node> trList = suggestionMenu.getElement().getChild(1).getChild(0).getChildNodes();
        for (int trIndex = 0; trIndex < trList.getLength(); ++trIndex) {
            Element trElement = (Element)trList.getItem(trIndex);
            if (((Element)trElement.getChild(0)).getClassName().contains("selected")) {
                trElement.scrollIntoView();

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This looks intriguing...
You say that this "avoids reimplementing SuggestBox"... but don't you have to at least reimplement SuggestBox constructor to construct with your ScrollableDefaultSuggestionDisplay, rather than the original DefaultSuggestionDisplay?  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I think I see it looks like you must be calling the public 3-arg SuggestionBox constructor, whose 3rd arg is a SuggestionBox.SuggestionDisplay (which your ScrollableDefaultSuggestionDisplay is a type of).

Comment: Yeah this works... ingenious solution @Perdi Estaquel!
It's the only solution I found on the web that does not hack into SuggestBox.
I imagine Mayumi would have accepted this answer if it came in time for them before they answered themself...

Answer (score 3):

Following [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/m5xLTW1vUdE/C5qpUo1gDNgJ) on Google groups, I implemented a similar solution which is a bit more concise due to the use of JSNI:

```
private class ScrollableDefaultSuggestionDisplay extends DefaultSuggestionDisplay {

    @Override
    protected void moveSelectionDown() {
        super.moveSelectionDown();
        scrollSelectedItemIntoView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void moveSelectionUp() {
        super.moveSelectionUp();
        scrollSelectedItemIntoView();
    }

    private void scrollSelectedItemIntoView() {
        getSelectedMenuItem().getElement().scrollIntoView();
    }

    private native MenuItem getSelectedMenuItem() /*-{
        var menu = this.@com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay::suggestionMenu;
        return menu.@com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MenuBar::selectedItem;
    }-*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the solution. I had to create my own suggest box based on GWT SuggestBox implementations. But follow below in custom implementaion:
-Place ScrollPanel to PopupPanel then place MenuBar to ScrollPanel
-In moveSelectionUp() and moveSelectionDown() of your new internal SuggestionDisplat implementation add the code below:

```
 panel.ensureVisible( menu.getSelectedItem( ) );
```

This is not achievable by extending the SuggestBox since we won't have access to selected
MenuItem unless overriding protected getSelectionItem() method as public method.

Finally add CSS:

```
max-height: 250px;
```

To the popupPanel in your display implementations.

Comment: See the other Answer here by Perdi Estaquel that does not require hacking into SuggestBox itself, but using a simple extention instead.