# scroll bug of suggest box in gwt

Tags: css, gwt, scroll, suggestbox

I am creating Suggestbox in my gwt project.I used the css trick to add a scrollbar on my suggest popup like below,

```
.suggestPopupContent{
 height: 183px;    
overflow-y: scroll;
text-align                   :    left;
cursor                       :    pointer;
cursor                       :    hand ;
```

}

it works, but there's a bug : if you use the arrow keys to navigate through choices, the scrolling does not follow.
Please help me to sort out this bug.
Thanks Rahul

Answer (score 0):

See this other Question/Answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24235088/1357094) for a solution that uses the same CSS you already have, but doesn't have to hack into SuggestBox like @DonX 's Answer here:  It extends SuggestBox instead, and relatively simply.