# Handling large amount of data in GWT ListBox

Tags: gwt, listbox, gwt-platform

I must do a RPC call when my Presenter is revealled. That call result in a String[] with large amount of data. But this call is very very slow. It takes about 1min to finish.

After some tests, i discovered that ListBox.addItem() takes over 30% of this call. It's a huge time for just add String on that Widget.

What can I do to minimize this time?

Assuming that i need to load everything when my Presenter reveal.

Things that I've already done:

- Put my Query inside a View(Doesn't affect too much)
- Server read a Txt file instead of call DB(worst then View).
- Use Collections classes ArrayList,Vector...(Vector reduced time by 5%)

I've noticed that GWT designed a [LightweightCollections](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/LightweightCollections) to improve use of Collections on Client side(It's my next step).

But what can I do about ListBox?

Comment: why are you trying to display so much data at once when user will be to see only 200 items at once?

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Too much choice is no choice.**

You will not be able to tune up GWT Listbox/ValueListBox for purpose of displaying such huge amount data ( i am guessing entries in 1000's considering 20 seconds i.e 30% of 1 min). GWT Listbox is meant for selection. You cannot expect user to see 1000's of values , scroll and then select. Its a **User Interaction nightmare**.

1. The right approach is use to Async loaded **SuggestBox** for such huge data. With SuggestBox you can filters and display lesser data as choice based on users input keys.
2. If using SuggestBox is not feasible you must give a try for **CellList** in Cell Widgets ( they might show better performance ) - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets
3. I am not sure but give GWTChosen a try - http://jdramaix.github.com/gwtchosen/

Comment: I Agree with you, but, it's an user specification.

Comment: Try and educate the user giving a "functional" alternate :)

Comment: I'll try GWTChosen, looks pretty good thanks for the tip. Also, use guava libraries ImmutableList.

Comment: If you want to do the above solution 1. with SuggestBox, you can make a simple extension of it if you want it to have a scrollbar too like ListBox, according to this other Question/Answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24235088/1357094